# Javascript: Why use Logical Operators along with Comparison Operator?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, comparison-operators

Why do we use logical operators along with comparison operators? I'm still quite new to coding, whenever my lecturers gave us some example they always write like this:

```
if (totalMark >= 0 && totalMark < 40) {
  finalGrade = "F";
  document.getElementById("final_grade").value = finalGrade;
  }
```

Why not just use comparison operator?

```
if (0 <= totalMark < 40) {
  finalGrade = "F";
  document.getElementById("final_grade").value = finalGrade;
  }
```

Is there any advantages of using one over the other or is it just the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (0 <= totalMark < 40) {
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. You're expecting it to check whether totalMark is in the range from `[0, 40)`. But what it's really going to do is evaluate it one piece at a time. It's going to check `0 <= totalMark` and get either a `true` or a `false`.

Let's say totalMark is a negative number, so you get `false` from this piece. The next thing it will compare is `false < 40`. That doesn't make much sense, but javascript will do its best. Following the obscure rules of javascript type coercion, `false` gets treated as `0` so it checks `0 < 40` which is `true`. Therefore, `0 <= totalMark < 40` resolves to true when totalMark is a negative number. In fact, if you walk through the other possibilities, it will *always* result in `true`.

In short, these comparison operators can only look at 2 things at once. And then you use `&&`'s and `||`'s to build up something larger.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second one is not working how you think it does.

With the second one, only `0<=x` condition is checked first. If that is true the second part does not matter.

```js
let x = 20;
if(0 <= x < 40) { console.log("yo2"); }
if(0 <= x < 10) { console.log("yo"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison `0 <= totalMark < 40` doesn't work as you would expect.

It first computes `0 <= totalMark` (assuming `totalMark = 10`) which becomes `true`. Then it compares `true < 40`. Here it casts `true` to a number and `1 < 40` becomes true.

Therefore it feels more like random behaviour, than the comparison you wanted. For instance you can try following example:

```js
const totalMark = 10

if (0 < totalMark < 20) console.log('0 < ... < 20')
if (20 > totalMark > 5) console.log('20 > ... > 5')
```

Answer (score 0):

`0 <= totalMark < 40` checks whether `totalMark` is in the interval [0, 40) in some languages — such as CoffeeScript and Python — but not JavaScript (as explained in other answers).

Indeed, you [can see](https://coffeescript.org/#try:0%20%3C%3D%20totalMark%20%3C%2040) that CoffeeScript compiles this code to the JavaScript code `0 <= totalMark && totalMark < 40`.